# Does go auto-bind funcs to struct?

Tags: go

Say I have this:

```
type Handler struct{}

func helper(f func()){
   f() // calls h.Mount() or just Mount() w/o reference to h?
}

func (h Handler) Mount() {}

func init(){
  h:=Handler{}
  helper(h.Mount)
}
```

when the helper func receives h.Mount (a func), can it call it directly, or does it need a reference to the handler h, to call it properly? This compiles and runs as is so idk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Go book refers to this as a method value.

> Usually we we select and call a method in the same expression, as in
>   p.Distance(), but it's possible to separate these two operations. The
>   selector p.Distance yields a method value, a function that binds a
>   method (Point.Distance) to a specific receiver value p. This function
>   can then be invoked without a receiver value; it needs only the
>   non-receiver arguments.

(Source: The Go Programming Language, Donovan and Kernighan, page 164.)

Comment: oh damn, i guess its not possible to change receivers then, but thats nbd

Comment: @AlexanderMills, yes you can, using a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions): `Handler.Mount` has type `func(Handler)`.